# QuickWatch is useless when debugging a LightSwitch HTML client application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

When debugging a LightSwitch (2013) HTML client application in Visual Studio the QuickWatch window only shows useless information. For instance for a 'screen' object:

- [prototype]
- _listeners
- details

No relevant properties are shown, just some stuff that looks like meta-information to me.

I'm not an expert in Javascript, so this could be normal, but it seems very odd to me.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Paul